# Is it possible to dynamically generate a cattr_reader hash from the database?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, metaprogramming

I'd like to know if I can add something similar to this in my class and have it build a class attribute that I can reference in other classes.  I don't want to have to remember id's and I don't want to keep having to update id's as the id's in the weight tables change.  Nor do I want to lock the weight table into a set of specific id's.

So I'd love to do something like the following:

```
class Weight < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  @@kind = {
    Weight.all.each do |weight|
      weight.name.delete(' ').underscore.to_sym: weight.id,
    end
  }
  cattr_reader :kind, :instance_accessor => false
end
```

Then in other areas of the code I can do things like..

```
scope :light, where(weight_id, Weight::kind(:light))
```

I'm sure there's some magic ruby way, I'm just not sure of the right syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the closest I've come so far.

```
def self.kinds
  kinds = Weight.all.map { |weight| { weight.name.delete(' ').underscore.to_sym => weight.id } }
  kinds.reduce({}, :update)
end
```

and then...

```
scope :light, where(weight_id, Weight.kinds[:light])
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not turn kind accessor into a class method which would lazily load the weights from database and lookup the neccessary one?

However, the stuff you are trying to do doesn't seem really good. What is the table behind Weight changes? What your classes will be loaded prior to the database connection gets set up (in some test environment, for instance)? I would suggest rewriting the scope to inner joing weight model with the appropriate name...